# About editing tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing

I follow [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology) tag, and once in a while there are questions related with algebraic topology, differential geometry and differential topology that are tagged with *general-topology*; as instance, CW-complexes, homotopy, differential maps, etc.

I would like to know if I'm acting in accord with the polices of the site when I remove *general-topology* tag and, if needs be, add *algebraic-topology*, *differential-geometry(topology)*, etc? Or should I only add tags to the question instead of removing *general-topology* tag.

Comment: Please, by all means remove the [tag:general-topology] tag from such questions.

Answer (score 11):

I have always taken removal of inappropriate tags to be a service to the community (and I say this without having an opinion on the question of whether or not general-topology is appropriate for the questions you ask about).