# Tag edits considered too minor?

Tags: discussion, tagging, review, suggested-edits, retagging

A Community Member recently [posted on Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11911/3111), asking about the appropriateness of editing solely to remove (inappropriate) tags.

The response was one of encouragement.  However I'm noticing in the review queue that some of these tag-only edits are being rejected by (well-meaning) Reviewers who consider them "too minor".

Perhaps the Reviewers would be reassured to know the Community supports this activity, and that [tag-only edits are not counted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2398/3111) toward Editor/Strunk & White/Copy Editor badges, so this Activity is intended as a service and not a "badge hunting" symptom.

Comment: I suspect an interaction with the new "status bar" function of advising me (and others with the ability to approve Edits) of items pending review.

Comment: Might this be related? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12111/rejecting-edits-because-user-were-retagging-many-very-old-questions

Comment: @MartinSleziak That could be a factor in some cases, but the two reviews in front of me were tag-only edits from today of a 2 hour old and a 2 day old Question, resp.  Probably should have made the recency issue part of my post...

Comment: You may want to support the proposal to [lower the requirement for retags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210709). SE messed up retagging this year. In a ridiculous chain of events, an interface change (moving the capability of `retag` button to `edit`)  led to policy change: retagging subjected to the same level of scrutiny as actual edits.

Comment: Retagging to remove inappropriate tags should be encouraged. Retagging to add an appropriate non-meta tag to a post with none should be encouraged. Retagging to add appropriate tags to a post that already has an appropriate non-meta tag requires more judgement. I wish the site distinguished between meta tags and others so posts would be *required* to have a non-meta tag.

Comment: @PostNoBills:  Thanks for pointing out the connection.  I'm of divided sympathies about equalized scrutiny for tag-only edits.  It seems your Edit here narrowly avoided being a tag-only one by removing one of my question marks from the title.  A double question mark was intended to convey mild astonishment about the standard "too minor" being applied, but I did intend there to be open discussion as well.

Comment: It's possible that MSE experience conditioned me to associate repeated punctuation marks with low quality content. It is uncommon for meta posts to contain `??`, and when they do, they are  [hardly worth reading](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%3F%3F).